# PromptDataSource in Delphi 7 is giving different results it did before

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado

In my Delphi 7 application it is possible to build connections to sql server and store the connectionstrings in an config file.
This has always worked without any troubles for years now.

The code for building the connection string is this :

```
procedure TDataModuleMain.GetADOProviderString;
var
  ConnectionString : string;
begin
  ConnectionString := PromptDataSource(Application.MainForm.Handle, cdsConnectionsADOConnectionString.AsString);

  if ConnectionString <> cdsConnectionsADOConnectionString.AsString then
  begin
    if not (cdsConnectionsADO.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then
      cdsConnectionsADO.Edit;
    cdsConnectionsADOConnectionString.AsString := ConnectionString;
  end;
end;
```

PromptDataSource is a function from the ADODB.pas and it brings up the 
`Microsoft datalink property window` and after configuring the connection the connectionstring is returned.

In the past I was able to uncheck `Blank password` and check `Allow saving password` and the password and `security info=true` was present in the returned connectionstring.
But this has changed some time ago, not sure when. The function now never returns the password and does not contains security info=true anymore. As a result these checkboxes always revert back and the password is always empty as in this screenshot : [image]

I suspect some windows update has done this to me, or could it be something else ?
I hope someone has encountered this and has a solution for it.

**EDIT 1**
It appears the problem only occurs when I choose `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` as Provider. When I choose `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server` there is no problem and everything works fine.
Is there a way to make the Native Client behave and also return the desired connectionstring ?
The OS I am testing on is Windows 8.1

**EDIT 2**
I tried setting the property persistant security info=true as suggested in the comments, but again this gets reverted when using the native client but not when using the OLE DB client

**EDIT 3**
I tried it by making a text file with extension .udl and doubleclicking on it, as suggested in the comments. The result is the same, it works for OLE DB provider but not for the native client

Comment: I think your q is missing a couple of items, namely which OS and which ADO provider are you using?

Comment: @MartynA I added the provider and the OS in my question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx

Comment: @Sami Thank you for the link, but I do not see anything in there about my problem. I could have overlooked it offcourse

Comment: There is `Trusted connection` and that what you use

Comment: @Sami Can you elaborate a bit more please. I need to login using username and password not by Integrated security. It works great, my only problem is that the Data Link Properties windows does not returns the password in the connectionstring, when the provider is the native client. How does Trusted connection can help me with this ?

Comment: Set `Trusted connection = False` then Save old password , then uncheck `Blank Password` and check `Allow Saving Password`

Comment: @Sami Where in the Data Link Properties window can I find this 'Trusted connection' ? I looked in the 'advanced tab' and in the 'All tab' but I just cannot find it

Comment: You can find all the properties in the last tab (N°4).

Comment: Try adding `Persist Security Info=True`

Comment: I did looked there and there is no 'trusted connection' in the last tab

Comment: @Kobik I just tried that it does not help. You can test it easy by making a text file with extension .udl and than set all the properties. When I set Persistent security info= true is just gets reverted back to false. This does not happen when the provider is the OLE DB only when its the native client

Comment: Have you tried this outside Delphi by double clicking the udl and editing it?

Comment: Yes, as I told in my last previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is `Persist Security Info=True` (which is BTW not recommended for security reasons). The thing about Native Client 10/11 is that any change to the user name or password in the Data Link dialog will *reset* `Persist Security Info` to `False`.

So you must enter the `All` tab *after* you change the username/password and change `Persist Security Info`  to `True`. You might be presented with an information dialog stating that saving an unencrypted password is not recommended.

[image]

Comment: Doing it in this order did the trick, thank you very much. The dialog box with the warning is no problem the users are already used to that. Also the connectionstring is stored encrypted in the config file so also no problem there